# About RISC-V compilers?

Tags: c, toolchain, riscv

I am new to programming and as well as RISC-V. I have a few questions regarding the RISC-V compilers:

- Do RISC-V compilers support the C program?
- From which RISC-V cross compiler can I generate ELF files that accept C program?
- Can anyone who is familiar with these things please help me in the learning process?

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain)?

Comment: the mainline gnu toolchain (gcc + binutils) supports risc-v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [RISC-V GNU Compiler Toolchain](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain). It is a cross compiler that makes it possible to build ELF files for RISC-V on a standard Linux system.

It can be a bit of a challenge to build a toolchain by yourself, but there seems to be good instructions for this one.

Often you get a pre-built toolchain from a supplier. If you have that I recommend you to use it instead of building one yourself.